# Solving $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ without a calculator

Tags: calculus, limits

Problem:

> $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

**Without a calculator**, what is the simplest method to solving this limit? I multiplied $\frac{1}{(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ by $\frac{(x-1)^{2/3}}{(x-1)^{2/3}}$ to get $\frac{(x-1)^{2/3}}{(x-1)}$. I then rewrote the limit as $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{(x-1)^{2/3}}{(x-1)}$ so I could get an indeterminate form. I then tried using l'hospital's rule but I got an undefined answer.

Comment: I believe it just diverges to negative infinity.

Comment: @JG123 How did you arrive at that conclusion? Could you explain it in an answer block for this question?

Comment: You can find the limit by substituting x=0.992,0.999,0.999999 and you’ll see that

Comment: The denominator approaches $0$ from the negative side, while the numerator remains constant.  Therefore the fraction approaches negative infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=x-1$. Then, $x\to 1^{-}\implies t\to 0^{-}$. So, we have the following:

$$
\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=
\lim_{t\to 0^{-}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{t}}=
\lim_{t\to 0^{-}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{t}}.
$$

The behavior of the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ is well known. As $t$ approaches $0$ from the left, the functional value is becoming an increasingly large negative number. So, again, let $u=\frac{1}{t}$. Then, $t\to 0^{-}\implies u\to -\infty$. Our limit now looks like this:

$$\lim_{u\to -\infty}\sqrt[3]{u}.$$

And what does the function $f(u)=\sqrt[3]{u}$ approach as its argument goes to negative infinity? Well, it also goes negative infinity:

$$\lim_{u\to -\infty}\sqrt[3]{u}=-\infty.$$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

$~x\to 1^-~$i.e., $~x~$ approaches $~1~$ from the left and  so $$~x\lt 1\implies x-1\lt 0\implies (x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\lt 0~$$
Therefore the denominator is a negative quantity  approaching $~0~$ from the left.

Hence $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=-\infty$$

Comment: The only part I don't get is how do we know the denominator is approaching 0? Is this because substituting 1 into the denominator yields 0 for the denominator?

Comment: $x\to 1~$ does not mean that you have to substitute $~1~$ in $~x~$. Actually by $~x \to 1~$ , you  have to consider the value of $~x~$ which is nearly equal to $~1~$(difference between $~x-1~$ is nearly equal to $~0~$ ). And for this case the denominator is so small that you can consider it is  nearly equal to $~0~$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 1^-}$ $\frac{1}{(x-1)^{1/3}}$=$\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, where $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal number just less than $0$. This can be seen by plugging in a number just less than $1$ into $(x-1)^{1/3}$. Thus, we have that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$=-$\infty$ because we are dividing 1 by a tiny negative number.

Comment: Of course, this is not rigorous by any means, but the idea is there.